# Incompatible types ddlutils catch block

Tags: java, javafx, exception, ddlutils

I am trying to write my database to XML using ddlutils, but I needed a try/catch block.  However, when I used the following code I am getting the error "Incompatible types:
Required: java.lang.throwable
Found: org.apache.ddlutils.DdlUtilsException"

```
public void writeDBToXML(Database db, String fileName) {
    try {
        new DatabaseIO().write(db, fileName);
    } catch (DdlUtilsException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `DatabaseIO` defined? What does it have in the `throws` clause of its constructor and `write` method?

Comment: DatabaseIO is a type included in the apache import

Comment: @sillyfly seems like the throws clause is  there ( https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api/org/apache/ddlutils/io/DatabaseIO.html#write(org.apache.ddlutils.model.Database,%20java.lang.String) ) and since the exception extends `RuntimeException` there should be no need for a `throws` clause...